# Python: Using .find() instead of .split()

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to print individual words in a string by using .find() instead of .split(). My code below will print the first two lines, then two blank spaces. I've tried using `space_index += quote.find(" ", space_index + 1)` on line 7, but that results in the program printing blank spaces forever. What am I missing?

```
  quote = "they stumble who run fast"
    start = 0
    space_index = quote.find(" ")
    while space_index != -1:
        print(quote[start:space_index])
        start += (space_index + 1)
        space_index = quote.find(" ", space_index + 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very close. Just changed the `+=` to an `=` when updating `start`. Remember that `space_index` is the index of the space in the whole string, not since the previous space.

```
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
start = 0
space_index = quote.find(" ")
while space_index != -1:
    print(quote[start:space_index])
    start = (space_index + 1)
    space_index = quote.find(" ", start)
print(quote[start:])
```

Comment: This still isn't quite it. This will only print _up to_ but not including the last word.

Comment: OP seems to be using Python 3, so add parenthesis for `print`. Also, `start` can be used instead of adding 1 to `space_index` again in `find()`.

Comment: @LadyFootlocker Great! Please accept the answer if you're satisfied.